# How to set root signatures specified in HLSL in my command list?

Tags: c++, hlsl, directx12

From [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/specifying-root-signatures-in-hlsl), I can specify the root signature of my shader in HLSL. How do I use it though?

Since at the beginning of the command list, root signature is undefined. I need to use `ID3D12GraphicsCommandList::SetComputeRootSignature(ID3D12RootSignature*)` or `ID3D12GraphicsCommandList::SetGraphicsRootSignature(ID3D12RootSignature*)` set root signature, but having specified in HLSL instead of C++ code, I do not have a pointer to my root signature objects, how should it be done then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide any compiled shader blob that contains the desired root signature defined in HLSL when creating the root signature object:

```
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D12RootSignature> m_rootSignature

// Create root signature.
auto vertexShaderBlob = DX::ReadData(L"VertexShader.cso");

DX::ThrowIfFailed(
    device->CreateRootSignature(0, vertexShaderBlob.data(), vertexShaderBlob.size(),
        IID_PPV_ARGS(m_rootSignature.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf())));

…

// Use root signature
commandList->SetGraphicsRootSignature(m_rootSignature.Get());
```

> The `DX::ReadData` function just loads the binary blob from disk (source [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/microsoft/DirectXTK/ReadData.h)). The `DX::ThrowIfFailed` helper is explained [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ThrowIfFailed).

If you are using `FXC.EXE` you can also build a shader with the HLSL defined root signature using the `rootsig_1_0` or `rootsig_1_1` profile and the resulting compiled binary object will just have the root signature in it.

Comment: That worked! I was used to using D3D12SerializeVersionedRootSignature to produce the blob and didn't know the blob from compiling the shader can be used for it as well. Thank you.